# Finding the max with velocity and acceleration graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

I'm confused on why there is a maximum at R. If I flipped the acceleration graph it looks like a continuously increasing function with no max or min to me. Could someone help me understand this? 8a (linear graph) is $f''(x)$
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative of $f(x)$ is zero at $x=r$, so $r$ is clearly a critical point. We see that $f'(x)$ is positive to the left of $r$ and negative to the right. With all these facts, the "first derivative test" shows that $f(x)$ is a maximum at $x=r$.

The First Derivative Test can be proven by using the Mean Value Theorem on any closed interval $[s,r]$ for $s$ slightly to the left of $r$ and again on $[r,t]$ for $t$ slightly to the right of $r$.

Note that only the first diagram was used here.